# kext delaying init until /dev is mounted

Tags: macos, kernel, bsd, kernel-extension

Quick question to see if there is an established method to handle the situation.

I set OSBundleRequired = Root, so that kext is loaded before root filesystem, so that we may offer mountroot. But as part of the kext ::start function, we create the /dev/ node to communicate with, which of course gets lost, since it is created before /dev is mounted.

Presumably some trigger, or hook is desired to initialise the /dev entry after mountroot, and devfs, has been set up.

Now, bsd_init does have mountroot_post_hook(), which looks to be clear for me to use, but I don't know if I should. Is there perhaps a more common way to handle a delayed init. IOkit event that comes in later?

Since neither HFS, nor NFS, create /dev nodes, they do not provide an answer, and apfs is not yet bootable.

Comment: I'd have to research if this works for your case, but the IOKit way for system initialisation events is normally to wait for the relevant `IOResources`. I'm not sure if the "BSD" level of IOKit initialisation covers /dev/, but I suspect it might.

Comment: Thanks pmdj (and evansus), in this case it was quite easy, changing the Info.plist from <key>IOResourceMatch</key><string>IOKit</string> to <string>IOBSD</string>.
It means vfs_mountroot is run before init, but that is how it is designed.